# Pagination - linking back to base page - Page 1

Tags: pagination

Well, I've had a look in a few places but couldn't find the answer.

So, the base page (page 1) has the same code as this and everything works. However when I pass page 1 and go to any other page when I try and go back to page 1 by placing nothing in the  like so it stays on the same page.

```
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
     <li><a href="page-2"><</a></li>
 <li><a href="">1</a></li>
<li><a href="page-2">2</a></li>
<li><a Class="active" href="page-3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="page-4">></a></li>
<li><a href="page-4">»</a></li>
```

Comment: please post the corresponding source code.

Comment: posted full HTML code below,

Comment: The full URL of the pagination is

Comment: www.homedecorhull.com/all-wallpaper/ so I want page 1 and other buttons to go to that page. However if I'm on say Page 2 or 3 or any others it defaults to that page when I leave the href empty "" like so? I'm not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
<style>
ul.pagination {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
color: black;
float: left;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background-color .0s;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
background-color: #f88017;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #f88017;}

div.center {text-align: center;}
</style>
  </head>
<foot>
<div class="center">
 <ul class="pagination">
 <li><a href="">«</a></li>
 <li><a href="page-2"><</a></li>
 <li><a href="">1</a></li>
<li><a Class="active"href="page-2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="page-3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="page-3">></a></li>
    <li><a href="page-4">»</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>

</foot>
 </html>
```